# Problema para salvar imagem em Node e React

Tags: node.js, react

Estou tentando fazer uploads de imagens no meu servidor utilizando node e React, no entanto, ao tentar fazer o upload, ele me gera essa mensagem:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/fakepat:3000/record/1h/pastedImage.png

Não consigo entender o que possa ser, alguém pra me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

React

```
handleAdd() {
    const id = this.state.id;
    const image = this.state.image;
    const description = this.state.description;
    const patient = this.state.patient;

    if (id === '') {
        axios.post(URL, { image, description, patient })
            .then(resp => this.refresh());
    } else {
        axios.put(`${URL}/${id}`, { image, description, patient })
            .then(resp => this.refresh());
    }
}
```

Node

```
router.post('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        var record = new Record({
            image: req.body.image,
            description: req.body.description,
            patient: req.body.patient
        });
        await record.save();
        res.status(201).send({
            message: 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Falha ao processar sua requisição'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Bota o codigo fonte de salvar porfavor

Comment: Provavelmente a pasta que você está tentando escrever o arquivo que subiu para o servidor, não da permissão de escrita para o node. Talvez um `chmod 775 upload` já resolva.